# scramble the value of one column and unscramble it?

Tags: sql-server

I want to change all the values in one column, as it is a production database and I don't want to give the data to testers without obfuscation.

Example:

```
Name             Name
----     -->     ----
ABC              BCD
PQR              QRS
```

I have searched scrambling and other things but my issue is I want to change the obfuscated data back to their original values when needed.

I need a generic script so I can apply it to an arbitrary table if required.

Comment: If you want to be able to easily change it back, what's to stop the testers also doing so? Normal Dev/Test/UAT procedures would involve using a separate database with 1-way obfuscated data, rather than messing with production.

Comment: On the other hand, why do you need to be able to restore original values?

Comment: @Andriy because the testers are going to be testing against the production database perhaps?

Comment: If a problem is found, the database should have unique keys to be able to backtrack to the original data without involving the visual representation of that data. If the database doesn't have that, fix that first.

Comment: Just to add you do not need to be able to revert obfuscated data to original values to do what you need; if a problem was identified then you would run a script to compare IDs against obfuscated IDs on the source system to find the relevant record.

Which leaves open the original idea to just mask the data however is convenient through a hashing function - except that this is going to be a real problem if you use client details as part of your ID keys.

Comment: @AndriyM - or, to be able to confirm what's been done in test against what's in production. Of course, if primary keys are not obfuscated, this should be possible without reverting the obfuscation, as [Jon Seigel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2718/jon-seigel) notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of generic data masking script, but the only problem is that **no one understands your data better than you**.

You have to write your own masking script based on **what data you consider sensitive**.

When you do a backup/restore of PROD data on UAT/QC environments for testing, its advisable to mask the data with dummy data. Masking of data can be done through updating the confidential information in the database like SSN , Password,Username etc with some other values.

You can even log what data is going to change in tables with different schema. For e.g

If person.Employee table is going to be masked, then the before value can be written to maskPerson.Employee table. This way, you will have before values as well. (dont really need this as in UAT or QC you dont care of the before value, which is PROD value you are masking).

Some good references :

- [Data Masking Script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9fc61236-fb49-4c58-8d9b-2edce1f1e06a)
- [Obfuscating your SQL Server Data](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/obfuscating-your-sql-server-data/)
- [Data Generator for SQL SERVER 2000,2005 and MSDE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13244/Data-Generator-for-SQL-SERVER-2000-2005-and-MSDE)

I found [this connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/485554/data-masking) wherein Microsoft is going to provide a data masking feature in future release ... (still could not make it for 2012).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use T-SQL built-in function `REVERSE`

```
SELECT 'Gorilla'                   AS original,
       REVERSE('Gorilla')          AS reversed,  --alliroG
       REVERSE(REVERSE('Gorilla')) AS unreversed
```

Comment: While this works well in certain cases (I've been known to transmit new password data to people using this method to obfuscate it), it does have its limits. I'm sure I'm not the only person who can read backwards text relatively easily, especially when you have cues (like capital letters at the ends of words; does anyone have much trouble "decoding" `tS niaM 321` even without using `REVERSE`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the classic UNIX rot13 method. Its simple and reversible. Just what the Dr. ordered.

I did find this page: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic579917-338-1.aspx about halfway down is a reasonable implementation of it in T-SQL.

I found mention of a DLL that you can plug in to SQL Server. I'm not sure if that is overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's current release of data masking tool is NOT for static data masking.

Pseudo-identification, or a technique of retrieving original values is a valid technique when environmental policies are properly upheld and sometimes there is a legit need. However, I would advise some thought put into propagation of the ids unchanged into testing environments. They are often displayed on the webpages - so you need to make sure that it is OK to move them as is.

There are techniques that allow backward lookup. However, there is an agreement in the industry not to propagate the knowledge freely - after all it is a security feature. Vendors often can do it and there is some academic literature on the subject. If you would like a webinar - you can use one from a reputable vendor, for example, from HushHush (www.mask-me.net) or from Camouflage (www.datamasking.com)