# Need to change alphanumeric characters to next character

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns `Name`, `Passport No.` in a table with more than 100k rows.

```
Name   Passport No.
KOP    A245
COS    C990
```

After the update it should look like this.

```
Name   Passport No.
LPQ    B356
DPT    D001
```

Update current character with the next character in the database. I don't want to select anything from table, I want to update the table.

Please don't ask me why.

Comment: Does Z become A?

Comment: Also is the only content in those columns upper case `A-Z` and `0-9`?

Comment: yes Z becomes A...A becomes B,B becomes C......And 9 becomes 0 ...and there are only A-Z and 0-9...

Comment: Do both columns have a fixed format as showed in your sample or data length is variable?

Comment: Data Length is varied...and data type is nvarchar..

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to ask why, I am going to say if this is being done to scramble your data for say testing or really anything else it's a REALLY bad idea.  That particular method is so transparent it's almost better just to leave it alone.

Comment: This is related to the OP's [previous question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47967/scramble-the-value-of-one-column-and-unscramble-it). OP, please merge your accounts to take ownership of that question. Your attempted edit was denied for that reason: http://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13171

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) to split your string and a case statement to figure out what the values your characters should have and `for xml path` to rebuild the string.

Put the logic in a function so it can be reused for multiple columns.

```
create function dbo.SS(@S varchar(max))
returns table as return
(
  select
  (
    select case
            when S.C = '9' then '0'
            when S.C = 'Z' then 'A'
            when S.C like '[A-Z,0-9]' then char(ascii(S.C) + 1)
            else S.C -- Keep not A-Z,0-9 as is
          end  
    from Number as N
      cross apply (select substring(@S, N.N, 1)) as S(C )
    where N.N between 1 and len(@S)
    for xml path(''), type
  ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') as C
)
```

This would be your update statement.

```
update YourTable
set Name = (select C from dbo.CC(Name)),
    [Passport No.] = (select C from dbo.CC([Passport No.]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot This works fine ..... But still one question ... when i m updating the function is converting space to next character....so i have added this case    when s.c = char(32) then ' '    .... but still showing some other characters...

Comment: @RajniPatel You said in a comment "there are only A-Z and 0-9" so I based my answer on that. What would you like to do with characters that is not A-Z or 0-9? I have updated they answer where the are kept as is.

Comment: `numbers table` link requires login :(

Comment: @jason the blog post is gone. Updated with a link to a so question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed by Mikael is absolutely great, but another option would be to use CLR function (although this is NOT the best approach for many reasons).

You can create a .NET class library (DLL) with similar code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

public class NextCharacter
{
    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None)]
    public static string Replace(string inputString)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        char[] charTable = inputString.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in charTable)
        {
            char x;
            switch (c)
            {
                case '9':
                    x = '0';
                    break;
                case 'Z':
                    x = 'A';
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    x = 'a';
                    break;
                default:
                    x = (char)(Convert.ToUInt16(c) + 1);
                    break;
            }
            output.Append(x);
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

then you'd need to enable CLR integration on your instance

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

and then just deploy the assembly to your database:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY NextCharacter from 'C:\NextCharacter.dll'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION NextCharacter(@input nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME NextCharacter.NextCharacter.Replace; 
GO
```

it will work just like a regular function:

```
SELECT dbo.NextCharacter('test');
GO

UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET 
     [Name] = dbo.NextCharacter([Name])  
    ,[Passport No.] = dbo.NextCharacter([Passport No.]);
GO
```